# using the checked property of HtmlElement Class

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to use the Checked property with the following code, but the word checked has an error saying it does not contain a definition. How do I use this property?

```
HtmlDocument document = webBrowser1.Document;    
HtmlElement agree = document.GetElementById("OptIn");
agree.Checked = false;
```

Comment: Which `HtmlElement` class? There are two different `HtmlElement` classes in .Net alone, plus things like HTML Agility Pack

Comment: @SLaks oh not sure i'm new to c# so i would have to add HTML Agility Pack to the namespace?

Comment: Try using `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("OptIn").SetAttribute("checked", "false");`

Comment: @wiz kid thanks! thats what I ended up doing